# Swagger.io / OpenAPI - How to reuse complete code blocks

Tags: yaml, swagger, openapi

I have status codes from the server that keep repeating in the documentation:

```
responses:
    '204':
      $ref: '#/components/responses/204'
    '400':
      $ref: '#/components/responses/400'
    '401':
      $ref: '#/components/responses/401'
    '402':
      $ref: '#/components/responses/402'
    '403':
      $ref: '#/components/responses/403'
    '404': 
      $ref: '#/components/responses/404'
    '426':
      $ref: '#/components/responses/426'
    '429':
      $ref: '#/components/responses/429'
```

How can I use Swagger.io's OpenAPI to lay a reference so that I only have one short line at a time, example:

```
responses:
    $ref: '#/components/responses/defaultCodes'
```

And is it also possible to expand the list with "allOf"?

```
responses:
    allOf:
    - '200':
      $ref: '#/components/responses/200'
    - $ref: '#/components/responses/defaultCodes'
```

Thank you very much for your help : )

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/guidelines/v2.0/REUSE.md

Comment: Not what I am looking for, but thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported.

Here are the related feature requests in the OpenAPI Specification repository:

- [Add default responses](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/563)
- [Traits or Mixins](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/613)
- [Group multiple parameter definitions for better maintainability](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/445) (even though it's about parameters, a generic solution could extend to responses)